# Integrating react-redux, react-final-form and react-bootstrap-typeahead

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-final-form, final-form, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I'm trying to setup `react-boostrap-typeahead` to get data from the `redux` store, and have the typeahead state be stored with `react-final-form`.
The problem is that `react-bootstrap-typeahead` has more than one piece of state attached to it, both which need tracking for this setup to work.

1. The text input state
2. The selected option

My preferred approach to solving this problem involves `final-form-set-field-data` and is illustrated here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/rl81o5765o

That code will not work correctly because the `Form` component is not aware of changes to a field's data.
Is there a better approach to solving this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with a solution here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/5m4w2909k

The approach is to introduce a `withKeyword` HoC that makes use of `final-form-set-field-data` to inject a `keyword` and `updateKeyword` props to the field.
A `Typeahead` must be connected to the `redux` store individually.

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem now. I need React-Select + React Final Form.
I tried to put up your example but gives me: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(GithubUserTypeahead)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(GithubUserTypeahead)".